# Javascript variable is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to add a background image slider in my Wordpress theme. But I need to add a JavaScript variable to slider function to get correct url for images. But the variable is not working it just printing itself without printing its value.

Here is my jQuery code and my variable name is 'turl'

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var turl = '<?= get_bloginfo("template_url"); ?>';
</script>
```

```js
$(function() {
    $.vegas( 'slideshow', {
        delay: 8000,
        backgrounds: [
            { src: turl+'bgslider/images/1.jpg', fade: 4000 },
            { src: turl+'bgslider/images/2.jpg', fade: 4000 }
        ]
    });   
});
```

Here is how it print in page source file ()

```
$(function() {
    $.vegas( 'slideshow', {
        delay: 8000,
        backgrounds: [
            { src: turl+'bgslider/images/1.jpg', fade: 4000 },
            { src: turl+'bgslider/images/2.jpg', fade: 4000 }
        ]
    });  
});
```

Comment: How come javascript snippet ended up outside `<script>` element?

Comment: Looks like a scoping issue. Try removing the `var` in front of `var turl`...

Comment: Dude thats the page source right. Then you will see the variable as it is. The value of the variable will be that url which you are setting.
You will have to echo it, the way you have echoed the url Example <?= get_bloginfo("template_url"); ?>

Comment: can we have the link please ?

Comment: @raina77ow Its inside <script> tag in actual code.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl I tried it. Not working :(

Comment: @SSS The variable 'turl' have the value. i used it in other places. The problem is its not working in the slider function especially inside   `backgrounds: []`

Comment: Try this 

{ src: ''+turl+'bgslider/images/1.jpg', fade: 4000 },
{ src: ''+turl+'bgslider/images/2.jpg', fade: 4000 }
I have added extra quotes at the beginning

Comment: Also try to console.log or alert the variable turl

Comment: @Khushboo Sorry now i'm working in local machine.

Comment: @SSS in console showing this "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/mak/NaNbgslider/images/1.jpg"

Comment: Is there any image on the url. Copy the url and paste in browser. If no then it will be url issue based on the PHP value you are setting.

Comment: This there any folder named NaN in the system and if yes try adding a '/' after "localhost/mak/NaN/bgslider/images/1.jpg"

Answer (score 0):

so:

```
<script>
 (function ($) { 
    $(function(){ 
    var turl = '<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>';
    $.vegas( 'slideshow', {
        delay: 8000,
        backgrounds: [
            { src: turl+'/bgslider/images/1.jpg', fade: 4000 },
            { src: turl+'/bgslider/images/2.jpg', fade: 4000 }
        ]
    }); 
    });
}(jQuery));
</script>
```

Comment: I try it but not working. I think its not the problem of assigning value to 'turl'. In my code the variable 'turl' have the value and its displaying when give alert inside $.vegas() like `$.vegas( 'slideshow', { alert(turl);...` But not working when given inside `backgrounds:[]`

Comment: In browser console its showing like this: "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - localhost/mak/NaNbgslider/images/1.jpg". the Variable not working properly. Not the problem of '/'

Comment: This construction perfectly works for me, so problem is in template url detection, so try to use this string without any variables: 
`{ src: '<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/bgslider/images/1.jpg', fade: 4000 },`